# Two apache servers using same port?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, ip, port, subdomain

so I have two apache servers on the same system.

Basically what I'm trying to figure out is if since I have 2 different IPs running on my system is it possible to have two different apache servers running on different IPs but using the default port(80) so the user doesn't have to specify the port in the address bar?

What I am trying to do is make it so that if the users visits:

example.com          ----> Apache Server 1 running on 1.1.1.1:80

mail.example.com     ----> Apache Server 2 running on 2.2.2.2:80

This would make it so that each domain would point to different apache servers but on the same system.

Thank you, JJ Edgar

Comment: You could do this, but I can't think of any reason why you'd want to have two separate copies of Apache running.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I want to do this because I have two different instances of apache in two different chroot's. One will contain our main websites being example.com and the other containing our mail server and cloud storage system.

Comment: Yes, this will work just fine. Just configure the Apaches to listen as you want them to.

Comment: Oh OK, that makes more sense. Though I'd probably have them in separate virtual machines for better separation.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Well I'm stuck with this for now. :/ Any ideas how I could get this to work?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Right now I'm getting the error: Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 but the only problem is, I don't have that in any configs at all. I have nothing but our secondary IP. Not sure why it is trying to bind to local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control which IP address Apache listens on using the `Listen` directive.

Just make sure that each server's configuration specifies only the IP addresses you want to use for that particular server.

For instance:

Server 1:

```
Listen 203.0.113.5:80
```

Server 2:

```
Listen 203.0.113.6:80
```

Any `<VirtualHost>` directives you use must also specify their IP addresses, rather than using the wildcard `*`.

See [the Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/bind.html) for further details.

Comment: This worked! Thanks a lot! The default is set to just '80' so for future reference to anyone just make sure you set it to 1.2.3.4:80 DO NOT FORGET THE PORT or you will get a start error! Thanks a lot Michael!